# XNA Level config file in C#

Tags: c#, xna, configuration-files

I'm working on as small game for class and was wondering what is a easy way to handel level configuration files. Like object placements , names, etc.

I'm new to C# but fluent in Java, Ruby.

so XML? YML? text, serialized objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that came to mind: LUA; it's pretty generic and there's a good class available for it: http://xnua.com/xna_lua_xnua

Comment: lua is a powerfull scripting language, i will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what you're doing.  I teach using XNA, and to my first semester students I recommend plain text files, and for my second semester students I have them use XML since XNA already has a content importer for XML.  Also keep in mind that lua/python cannot be used on the 360 because both use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xml files, xna has a greate serializer for working with these. It's called the [IntermediateSerializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/archive/2009/03/25/automatic-xnb-serialization-in-xna-game-studio-3-1.aspx).